# Python - global class that can be reused

Tags: python

I have a config var in the main class that I use a lot and I also pass it to some other instances that pass it to other classes, and so on.

I need a solution that can be used globally, without the need of passing an instance of the config file, and that I can modify as needed (not const).
something that only requires import anywhere and that the data will be the same and up to date.

In Java, I know that I can Autowired and I know that behind the scenes I'll use the exact same instance.

What solution does Python have?

example

*util.py*

```
config = None
setConfig(self, config):
    self.config = config

getConfig(self):
    return self.config
```

*file1.py*

```
....
import util
util.setConfig(4)
```

*file2.py*

```
import util
util.getConfig()
```

*file3.py*

```
import util
util.setConfig(8)
```

*file4.py*

```
import util
util.getConfig()
```

*main.py*

```
file1()
file2() # ==4
file3()
file4() # ==8
file2() # ==8
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a class attribute rather than instance attribute. Or a global variable.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking and the specific problem you are having.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the feedback - I'm new here. I'll edit the question

Comment: Anyway, as stated above, you could just make the variable a class variable (static) or just use a module global variable, although, explicitly passing the config would be the best practice, IMO

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why do you think it's the best practice? passing it to a great-grandchild can be complicated and the maintenance can be hard as well.

Comment: Because passing dependencies explicitly as arguments is good. This often goes by the fancy  name "dependency injection". I don't know what you mean by a "great grandchild". Anyway, your example is not helpful, it doesn't make sense. You really need to provide a [mcve]. Your `getConfig` and `setConfig` functions don't make sense, and would raise errors due to missing arguments if you tried to call them the way you show above. Your `main` module makes no sense. You also mentioned a class, but there are no classes anywhere